# serverless events are missing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a problem with my serverless configuration resulting in lambda functions being deployed without their triggers.

I have a main serverless.yml for my skills, as below:

service: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):service}

```
provider:
  name: aws
  custom:
    globalSchedule: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):globalSchedule}
    roleName: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):roleName}
    profileName: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):profileName}
  plugins:
    - pluginHandler
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  cfLogs: true

  stage: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):stage}
  region: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):region}
  memorySize: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):memorySize}
  timeout: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):timeout}
  keepWarm: false
  useApigateway: false
  events:
    ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):events}

package:
  exclude:
    ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):exclude}
functions:
  smartHome:
    handler: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):handler}
```

Then, I have two sets of yaml settings files. One for ${skill_type}_${localization} ie `customskill_eu.yml` and another stage-specific ${skill_type}*${localization}*{$stage} like `smarthome_us_dev.yml` etc.

```
service: alexa-SmartHomeSkillAdapter
exclude:
  - app.js
  - .idea/**
  - .npmignore/**
  - .jshintrc
  - build/**
  - documentation.docx
  - dist/**
  - event.json
  - lambda_function_custom_skill.js
  - resources/**
  - custom_skill_eu.yml
  - custom_skill_us.yml
  - smart_home_eu.yml
  - smart_home_us.yml
  - serverless_settings/**
  - tests/**
events:
  - s3: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):s3}
  - alexaSmartHome: amzn1.ask.skill.d48263be-c7ef-4d61-a773-d6431567e6d6
```

What is wrong? Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: @Anthon - why did you edit my tags?

Comment: Your files are correct YAML, and your question has as much to do with YAML as with e.g. ASCII. Read the tag description for YAML and you'll see it is inappropriate and misleading.

Comment: In my opinion, when a person who does nothing to help down-votes someone, perhaps to earn a useless badge, it says everything there is to say about that. If I was to rephrase my favorite movie character...

Comment: If people down vote your question the reasons can be any of: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Down voting is often necessary as part of our effort to create a database with **quality** questions and answers (which is the goal of [so]), and so it is a feature of this site with a purpose. Apart from that you already have shown your resistance to wanting to be helped by reverting improvements to your post, where in fact further improvements where necessary. A better question is much more likely to attract answers.

Comment: One common reason is a someone unable to provide constructive input would do something totally useless so that he/she feels important. You @Anthon would not know anyone like that, right? Even if you vote both my questions and profile down to nothing, I would still not feel offended and understand that you require treatment and compassion.

Comment: What needs treatment here is your post, but instead of improving that, you spent your time in taking it personal to one of the people who tries to help you learn how to use this site. A little effort could possible have made this an acceptable post, but since there are none: -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add events to your functions. Have a read through the serverless [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/events/) for events.

Currently serverless supports lambdas to be invoked by API GateWay, Kinesis, DynamoDB, S3, Schedule, SNS, and Alexa Skill. *([read more](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/))*

So in this case, adding a required `events` tag should solve your problem.

```
...
functions:
  smartHome:
    handler: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):handler}
    events: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):events}
...
```

Alternatively, you can always define all resources and their actions using traditional CloudFormation format within serverless `resources` node.

Comment: Well, I thought that is exactly what I need - added events to function configurations. My configuration is above. Do you see something odd with my it?

Comment: The first thing you'll need to do, move your events tag to reside within the functions element. Please see the example in the updated answer.

Comment: thank you, started looking. appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right.

I am still getting an error, but another one now. The original problem has been solved. Now, for some reason, when I use `events: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):events}` much like I did for excludes, exactly like you suggested, it tells arguments must be an array instead of string.

Hope to figure that one out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Found a serverless PR to deal my last problem. Thank you @lebryant for helping with configuration.